# Python error with OpenLayers plugin QGIS 2

Tags: qgis, python, error, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I've been using QGIS for a while but since using QGIS 2 the OpenLayers plugin doesn't work for me on my home PC. However, I have installed the same version at my workplace with success. I have looked through other posts, and tried setting the CRS and allowing on the fly but it doesn't work for me.

Can anyone offer any other guidance?

I have also tried uninstall/ re-install.

Error code below:

> An error has occurred while executing Python code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Lee/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 48, in addLayer
>       self.**plugin.addLayer(self)
>     File "C:\Users\Lee/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 194, in addLayer
>       layer = OpenlayersLayer(self.iface, self.__coordRSGoogle, self.olLayerTypeRegistry)
>     File "C:\Users\Lee/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 64, in __init**
>       self.page = OLWebPage()
>     File "C:\Users\Lee/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 38, in **init**
>       proxy = getProxy()
>     File "C:\Users\Lee/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\tools_network.py", line 42, in getProxy
>       proxy.setPort(settings.value("/proxyPort", 10, type=int))
>   TypeError: unable to convert a QVariant of type 10 to a QMetaType of type 2
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, d94c044
>
> Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing', 'C:\Users\Lee\.qgis2\python\plugins\GeoCoding', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:\Users\Lee/.qgis2/python', 'C:\Users\Lee/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Users\Lee\.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Comment: Do you use the same browsers at work/home?  Are the proxy settings identical?

Comment: Are you using OpenLayers Plugin version 1.1.1?

Comment: See if this [workaround](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9058) is successful.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Ill check the proxy at work, but have noted that I can access the plugin in QGIS 1.8 but not in QGIS 2.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I looked at your workaround, and played with the proxy settings. Unchecking the 'Use proxy for web access' box in options allowed the plugin to work for me at home. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you all. But your suggestions don't work for me. I think the problem is not about the proxy. It's QGIS's file system. You may see there are two types of slash in the same directory. I'm trying to find the answer to correct the direction. "C:\Users\Lee/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the OpenLayers plugin fails with an error in 'getProxy', verify that the proxy settings in the options menu are correct.

Answer (score 5):

FIY, the QGIS dev are thinking about [deprecating the OpenLayers plugin](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2015-December/040842.html) in favor of **QuickMapServices** (already available in the extensions)

Why? It's mainly an outdated plugin you should avoid. It was useful some years ago but it doesn't deal well with projections.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution was

settings>option>network (uncheck proxy)

And this was the end of my problem