# Python code error when using QGIS plugin Openlayers

Tags: qgis, python, openlayers-2

I am getting this error message whenever I try to use the Openlayers plugin. I can not read or write Python particularly well at the moment, though I am trying to learn, so I am struggling to identify the problem. I have tried un-installing and reinstalling openlayers plus using it on previous versions of QGIS with no success. Basic attempts but really haven't got the time to delve deeper into more complex procedures with out really knowing what I'm doing.

```
"An error has occurred while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 97, in addLayer
    self._addLayerCallback(self)
  File "C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 130, in addLayer
    layer = OpenlayersLayer(self.iface, self._olLayerTypeRegistry)
  File "C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.olWebPage = OLWebPage(self)
  File "C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 48, in __init__
    proxy = getProxy()
  File "C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\tools_network.py", line 42, in getProxy
    proxy.setPort(settings.value("/proxyPort", 10, type=int))
TypeError: unable to convert a QVariant of type 10 to a QMetaType of type 2

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS version:
2.10.1-Pisa Pisa, d20c5b7
Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', u'C:/Users/*****/.qgis2//python', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'C:/Users/*****/Documents/*****/*****']
```

Comment: A search for the error "TypeError: unable ... " gives this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/78248/8673 
Are you using a proxy?

Comment: Default proxy had been turned on. Turned it off, it all works now. Thank you!